# Where to get Microsoft Drivers?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, microsoft-surface

I'm consulting this community because Google searching, and MS physical service center as well as online support have failed me.

My surface pro 3 keyboard stopped working, and I took it to the service center. They said they found the problem, my computer is missing the Surface Type Cover Filter Device driver. They also wrote down the [MS website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38826) where I could find the driver. However you will notice, all that can be seen is this:

[image]

It's just a bunch of confusing/ prosaic sounding updates. There is no way of knowing where the driver I need is supposed to be.

While googling what to do, the consensus appears to be that you should uninstall the driver, restart the surface pro and it will automatically reinstall the driver. My issues with that are:

1. Surface Type cover Filter Device does not appear in my device manager
2. After shutting down and restarting, the driver is not installed
3. Volume up and power button for 10 seconds also does not install the missing driver

I'd rather not interact with the service center again.

If someone knows where I can get a stand alone copy of Surface Type Cover Filter Device, that would be great.

UPDATE

Over a week later, I still can't get the driver back. I ran into another issue, where whenever my Surface Pro 3 finishes installing the update from the MS website and prompts me to restart, it freezes each and every time. I humored it and let it try to complete, but it was unresponsive for 2 hours. It simply says: "Surface". Nothing else. At which point I have to volume button + power to revive it.

Is there some way to download a specific driver (in my case: Surface Type Cover Filter Device driver) and apply it without the Surface needing to restart? I have had bad luck whenever prompted to restart. The options in Device Manager seem very limited, there is no way to have it search for missing drivers. I also have a sinking feeling it doesn't even detect that it is missing a driver for my keyboard. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: From the details of that page: `Cumulative and current firmware and drivers for the Surface Pro 3.` Likely `SurfacePro3_Win10_1700802_1.msi` is going to be the whole and current driver or if you're running Windows 8 as your tags indicate `SurfacePro3_Win8x_161602_0.msi`.

Comment: Updating the firmware may not be a bad idea either.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on my 3rd Surface Pro 4 now within 17 months; each time the type cover problem (and some other backed-in 'problems' or after installing the Anniversary Update - don't!!) led to a full service new delivery, MS has no solution yet (May 17th 2017) and stalls is for the 3 and 4 users to order the new Surface Pro. Several times I spend hours on the phone with their technicians (situated all around the world) and they can take-over your Surface, fix it, but when the user for example uses the Dock, a new mouse, etc. (there are tons of reasons) the type cover driver disappears again. I know that if you allow MS to key-log your device all becomes more easy ... but I'd like to keep at least the illusion of a bit of privacy, so now way I'll go for that 'solution'.

The workaround that works every ones of out 4 tries (sometimes many more) is to, while running the Surface, do the switch-off/volume-up trick after you uninstalled the keyboard driver and then it restart from the boot-screen that turns up.

Must say, for the status MS tries to uphold with their software this is a very sad situation of course. Should have been fixed at least half a year ago. So also with this brand new Pro 4 the same problem - on my way to number 4 (for free, if not I will team up with Google/Samsung after 27 years of MS for sure).

Answer (score 0):

The one you need is most likely `SurfacePro3_Win8x_161602_0.msi`. Try that first. If that doesn't work, go back to MS support and ask them which file.

After you install, reboot and then check Windows Update for any subsequent updates.

I'd also recommend upgrading to Windows 10 as you will get further updates and better stability.